# Flask-Uploads IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, file-upload, flask, flask-uploads

So, I've been trying to add an image uploader to my code, but I've been running into issues.  Even though I thought I had my `upload_folder` configured properly, I keep getting errors like: `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/static/uploads/compressor.jpg'`  even though the file/directory exists.

Here's the code:

### in config.py

```
UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'static/uploads'
```

### in **init**.py

```
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
```

### in views.py

```
@app.route('/fileupload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #check if the post request has the file part
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['file']
        # if user does not select file, browser also
        #submit an empty part without filename
        if file.filename == '':
            flash('No selected file')
            return redirect(request.url)
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            return redirect(url_for('uploaded_file',
                                    filename=filename))
    return '''
    <!doctype html>
    <title>Upload new File</title>
    <h>UPload new file</h1>
    <form action="" method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
        <p><input type=file name=file>
            <input type=submit value=Upload>
    </form>
    '''

@app.route('/uploads/<filename>')
def uploaded_file(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],
                               filename)
```

My folder structure is as follows

```
  /project folder
   --/app
   ----/static
   --------/uploads
   ----/templates
   ----_init__.py
   ----views.py
   --config.py
```

When I use /tmp/ to store it in memory the uploader works no problem.  I assume it's not looking in the proper path for my folder.  Can anyone help here?  I'm a very amateur python developer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Both `/tmp` and `/static/uploads/..`, are absolute paths. And your code is looking in the `/` folder instead of looking in your project's folder. You should use the absolute path to point at your folder `/path/to/your/project/static/uploads/..` or use a path relative to the code being executed such as `./static/uploads`.

You can also use the following snippet to generate the absolute path:

```
from os.path import join, dirname, realpath

UPLOADS_PATH = join(dirname(realpath(__file__)), 'static/uploads/..')
```

Comment: I've seen this suggestion before, but maybe I'm implementing it wrong? For example, I just changed my UPLOAD_FOLDER to `UPLOAD_FOLDER = './static/uploads/'` and this is the error it's returning:  `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './static/uploads/Bathroom_Kitchen_Home_Decor_Outdoor__More_-_Google_Chrome_2016-06-18_13.32.14.png'`

Comment: Made some changes to my code just to test.  Ended up getting the exact same errors: `upload_form = UCGUploadForm()
    if upload_form.validate_on_submit():
        filename = secure_filename(upload_form.photo.data.filename)
        upload_form.photo.data.save(UPLOAD_FOLDER + filename)
    else:
        filename = None`      I also adjusted Forms.py.      `class UCGUploadForm(Form):
    photo = FileField('image', validators=[
        FileRequired(),
        FileAllowed(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png'], 'Images only!')
    ])
    `

Comment: Just to be sure, does it work properly on `/tmp`? if so, it should be a path problem: weather it's the wrong path, or the wrong permission. In the debugging process, print the value of the path from within the function and try to access it with the same user. I'm going to edit my answer to add a more pythonic way to get the correct path to your resource.

Comment: Just saw your second comment about OS path. That changed the error message! `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/ubuntu/workspace/static/uploads/..IMG_0334.jpg'`  So now I just have to find the right folder within my workspace.  Alternatively, how would I set this path to relative so that I can use the `./static` option?

Comment: I tried adjusting it from realpath to relpath, but was encountering the same error as before.

Comment: Sorry for so many comments here.  I adjusted my code for the upload folder to be basedir + filename (basedir is `basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))` which didn't return an error after testing!  It grabbed workspaceurl/uploads/filename, but returned a "file not found"

Comment: In my case, putting a '/' in front of 'static' had caused the problem in os.path.join function. Putting '/' in front of the second parameter omits the first parameter of the join and directly behaves like the root folder 'c:\static\'.

Comment: Thank you, wasted two hours on this problem

Answer (score 16):

This worked for me:

```
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

file.save(os.path.join(basedir, app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
```

Comment: upvoted. Also wanted to add that best use `os.path.join("path", "to", "your", "folder")` as this is OS independent opposed to `path/to/your/folder` which is not

Comment: @jidesakin - Thank you so much. Your solution works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

@jidesakin's solutions works but here is another solution:

Move your uploads folder from static directory back to your project directory where your app folder is, the folder where your app and environment folders are.

Your structure will be like:

```
'projectfolder
--/app
      --config.py
      --__init__.py
------/static
------/templates
------config
--uploads
```

Then change the content of you upload folder from 'static/uploads' to  'uploads' ...

Answer (score 0):

In **init**.py

```
app.config.from_mapping(
    SECRET_KEY='dev',
    DATABASE=os.path.join(app.instance_path, 'database.sqlite'),
    UPLOAD_FOLDER= os.path.join(app.static_folder, 'uploads'),
    ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS=set(['.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.gif']),
)
```